# (Django) How can I display an image that was processed in views.py?

Tags: python, html, django

I have a Django app with the following files:

models.py

```
class Document(models.Model):
    docfile = models.ImageField(upload_to='documents')
```

views.py

```
def Smaller(image):
    return image[0:32,0:32]

def upload(request):
    # Handle file upload
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = DocumentForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            newdoc = Document(docfile=request.FILES['docfile'])
            newdoc.save()
            image = get_object_or_404(Document, pk = newdoc.id)
            processed_image = Smaller(image.docfile.url)
```

And I want to display processed_image in the template output.html.

output.html

`<img src="{{ _______ }}" alt="processed_image" style="width:384px;height:384px;border:0;" align = "center"/>`

I also have a return `render(request, 'output.html', {'input': image})` as my final line in `upload(request)`, but of course it will only work on the original image.

Any suggestions as to how I can do this?

Comment: What kind of object is `image`?..

Comment: Actually, that's another concern. `image` should be an image (which is what the user will upload). But after going through the model, it doesn't seem to be processed as such.

Comment: Is `image` a model instance? What I would suggest is taking a look at a project like this one: https://github.com/skitoo/django-thumbs

Comment: What do you do with `processed_image` after you call Smaller?

Comment: With your method, you would need to send this to your context to use it in a template. I have a feeling though the package I linked above might have some features you you could use.

Comment: If image is a model instance, have you tried `{{ image.image.url }` in your template?

Comment: @DanielRoseman I want to display processed_image in my template (shown as _____)

Comment: That didn't answer the question in any way at all. What happens to it in your code? Do you save it anywhere?